# SQLiteman help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

Hi I need some help for a uni assignment, I need to answer 2 questions:
1) List the titles of videos that are available in more than one format together with the number of different formats available for each title.

**MY query was:**

```
SELECT title
FROM video
WHERE video_id IN (
    SELECT video_id, COUNT(format_id) AS AvaliableFormats
    FROM video_format
    GROUP BY title
    HAVING COUNT(format_id) > 1);
```

But the result says "Query Error: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression"- I'm not sure what this means or what I need to do to fix it?

**Q 2** 5) List the titles of videos that have an average cost (across formats) that is more than $2.

**My Query**

```
SELECT title
FROM video
WHERE video_id IN (
    SELECT video_id
    FROM video_format   
GROUP BY title
HAVING AVG(cost) > 2);
```

But it only brings up one result (row there should be 2).

If anyone can please help I would really really really appreciate it!

Comment: It would help if you showd us the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

The first is:

```
    SELECT title FROM video WHERE video_id IN ( SELECT video_id FROM 

video_format GROUP BY title HAVING COUNT(format_id) > 1)
```

If you are using `IN` only one column can be inside the inner query otherwise use `Exist`

The 2nd:

```
    SELECT title FROM video WHERE video_id IN 
( SELECT video_id FROM video_format
    GROUP BY video_in HAVING AVG(cost) > 2)
```

If I understood correctly and  the video in relates to title one by one, you made a bit   mess with the `group by`.

Comment: I don't think the first section will answer her question...she needs the number of formats for each title so would have to join the video_format table.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1

The error message means you cannot select multiple columns in a sub query. If you need the columns in the subquery consider using a join instead.

```
SELECT v.title, vf.AvaliableFormats 
FROM video v 
Join 
(
SELECT video_id, COUNT(format_id) AS AvaliableFormats 
FROM video_format 
GROUP BY title 
HAVING COUNT(format_id) > 1
) vf on v.video_id = vf.video_id
```

Question 2
Try grouping by video_id instead of title, two different films could have the same title.

```
SELECT title FROM video 
WHERE video_id IN 
(
SELECT video_id 
FROM video_format
GROUP BY video_id 
HAVING AVG(cost) > 2
)
```